# Cluster de conexões para MS SQL Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Estou precisando criar um Cluster de conexões para o MS SQL Server.

Segue exemplo que realizei no MySQL:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var db_cluster_config = require('./dbMysqlUtils').cluster_config;

var mySqlDB = function (config, logConfig) {
   this.cluster = mysql.createPoolCluster(db_cluster_config);
   this.cluster.add('Cfg', config);
   this.cluster.add('Log', logConfig);
   this.configs = { cfg: config, log: logConfig };
}
```

Mas não funciona para o MS SQL Server.

Comment: Mas você está utilizando o módulo `mysql`. Como quer que funcione para o `SQL Server`? Aqui vai o link para o módulo do [`mssql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql).

Comment: Eu fiz o do mysql, coloquei ele somente como exemplo para terem uma noção do que preciso. Agora na aplicação do mssql já estou usando o módulo mssql, mas não consigo montar o cluster.